# removing 'skrollr' on mobile screens

Tags: php, css, jquery-mobile, skrollr

I am trying to remove the skrollr functions on mobile (max width 767px) screen.

I have the following code that (it is assumed) to stop skrollr on mobile but it doesn't work (I have tried putting it in a seperate, enquened file and put it in the skrollr code itself, no change)

JAVA code

```
$(function () {
// initialize skrollr if the window width is large enough
if ($(window).width() > 767) {
skrollr.init(yourOptions);
}

// disable skrollr if the window is resized below 768px wide
$(window).on('resize', function () {
if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
}
});
});
```

code at the bottom of footer.php (to make skrollr work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        skrollr.init({
        forceHeight: false
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ + tablets
    (function(a) {
         if(/android|avantgo|bada\ ... )
     {
        //Add skrollr mobile on mobile devices.
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/skrollr.mobile.min.js"><\/script>');
     }
    })(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing skrollr in the footer.php regardless of the current window width. The condition in line 3 of your JAVASCRIPT file - `if ($(window).width() > 767) {` - does work, but skrollr is already initialized at this point by the javascript in your footer.php

I would recommend you to remove the initialization of skrollr in the footer.php file and modify your javascript code to something like this:

```js
(function($) {
    $(function () {
        var skrollrInstance;
        var onResize = function () {
            var isMobile = $(window).width() <= 767;
            if (!skrollrInstance && !isMobile) {
                skrollrInstance = skrollr.init({
                    forceHeight: false
                });
            } else if(skrollrInstance && isMobile) {
                skrollrInstance.destroy();
                skrollrInstance = null;
            }
        };
        $(window).on('resize', onResize);
        onResize();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erfvgx85/2/ (resize the "Result" frame to test it)

I have stored the current skrollrInstance in a separate variable. As you have commented, "// skrollr.init() returns the singleton (instance) created above", but it could be a performance issue if skrollr isn't initialized or already destroyed at this moment.

I also think that it's nicer to just have one place for the call of skrollr.init - otherwise we could forget to pass the same options (forceHeight: false) in another call. (like in your example)

Comment: If I remove the code from footer.php then Scrollr doesn't work at all, That is where it is called

Comment: when I remove the footer script from the footer.php it does not use scrollr at all. Where would I put the java from the fiddle you made

Comment: You can either put the JavaScript code in a separate JavaScript file (e.g. a file called script.js) and include it using a script tag - e.g. `<script src="script.js">` - or put the code directly in footer.php like before. Let me note that "java" is a completely different programming language, we are currently talking about JavaScript code.

Comment: so i completely remove the footer <script> from my footer.php and put in your code. I understand I can't put your code directly in script tags.  Another question is that is it written in conflict free mode?

Comment: I put the java code in a file (mobile-fix.js) as your wrote it, and replaced the script in the bottom of footer.php with just <script src="mobile-fix.js"></script>. But skrollr doesn't work now on any screen size.

Comment: Ah, it seems you are using wordpress. I have updated my post - the script will now work in conflict free mode. Double check that you are loading the libraries skrollr and jquery beforehand and check your Javascript Console in your browser for errors. Regarding your script in the footer.php: I asked you to remove only the first script tag which initializes skrollr. The second script tag loads the skrollr.mobile.js library on mobile devices, which is just fine.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I got it to work now, thank you very much. I have an opacity change on text at a certain height from the top. When on mobile screen size, the text condenses and takes up more height so fades to soon. I decided to just remove skrollr on mobile size screens to fix that